# Android - how to speed up my app?

Tags: java, android, lag

I'm developing an Android application with many data retrieve from sqlite database, json request, Google maps and recyclerView.

The problem Is that The application Is slow and with a lot of lag. 
I'm already using asynctask classes for json request or adapter but Is there a way to get The data from db and swap recycler view's items in time and more quickly?

I'm was reading about custom loader , but I don't know if it can be useful for me.

```
/**
 * Fragment for Bus function
 */
public class BusFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<Fermata> myDataset;
    public View view;
    private static final String TAG_LOG = BusFragment.class.getName();
    private final String MAP = "BUS";
    Polyline line;
    /**
     * This is the request code we use for the onActivityResult management
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /**
     * The GoogleApiClient we use to interact with Location Services
     */
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * The last location
     */
    public static volatile Location mLastLocation;

    /**
     * The Fragment for the Map
     */
    public SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;


    /**
     * The handle to manage Google Map
     */
    public GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    /**
     * The implementation of the interface to manage CallBacks from Google Play Services
     */
    private final GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Connected");
            // We update the data into the View with the first location
            try {

                final Location firstLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                mLastLocation = firstLocation;
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.");
        }
    };

    /**
     * The implementation of the interface we use to manage errors from Google Play Services
     */
    private final GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener mOnConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            // This is invoked when we have an error in Google Play Services management.
            // We have to check if there is a standard resolution for this
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                // In this case we launch the Intent to manage the problem
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(),
                            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // In case Play Services cancels the Intent
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // In this case there's no standard resolution for the error so we can
                // only show a Dialog with the error
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Error:" + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mOnConnectionFailedListener)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Dentro onStart");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * Method to require Location Updates
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setSmallestDisplacement(10).setInterval(6000);
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                            mLastLocation = location;
                            new UpdateLocationRecycler().execute();
                        }
                    });

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_fragment,
                container, false);

        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

                                         googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onMapLoaded() {
                                                 new getDistanceTask().execute();
                                                 startLocationUpdates();


                                                 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                                         if (line != null) {
                                                             line.remove();
                                                         }

                                                         ArrayList<String> mark = new ArrayList<String>();
                                                         mark.add(JsonUtility.createJsonUrl(mLastLocation,LocationUtility.getLocationFromLatLng(marker.getPosition()),Const.MODE_WALKING));

                                                         new JSONParse().execute(mark);

                                                         return false;
                                                     }
                                                 });


                                             }
                                         });
                                     }
                                 }
        );
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bus_stop_recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        final BusStopAdapter mAdapter = new BusStopAdapter(myDataset,mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }







    /**
     * AsyncTask class to manage json request
     */
    public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, String, ArrayList<JSONObject>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<JSONObject> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... args) {
            ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < args[0].size(); i++) {
                array.add(JsonUtility.getJSONFromUrl(args[0].get(i)));
            }

            return array;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONObject> array) {
            ArrayList<List<LatLng>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = array.get(i);
                list.add(PolylineUtility.listPolyline(json.toString()));
            }
            PolylineUtility.drawPath(list,mGoogleMap);

        }
    }


    private class getDistanceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, BusStopAdapter> {
        ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        TextView mLoading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bus_stop_recycler_view);
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            mLoading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.loading);


        }

        @Override
        protected BusStopAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
            publishProgress("Loading...");
            BusUtility busUtility = new BusUtility();
            myDataset = SplashScreenActivity.fermatas;
            final BusStopAdapter mAdapter = new BusStopAdapter(myDataset,mRecyclerView);

            return mAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(BusStopAdapter mAdapter) {
            super.onPostExecute(mAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            View progress = view.findViewById(R.id.loading_layout);
            ((ViewGroup) progress.getParent()).removeView(progress);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            mLoading.setText(values[0]);
        }
    }

    private class UpdateLocationRecycler extends AsyncTask<Void, ProgressBar, List<Fermata>> {
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progess_update);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Fermata> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            publishProgress(mProgressBar);
            BusUtility busUtility = new BusUtility();
            myDataset = busUtility.dist(mLastLocation);
            return myDataset;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Fermata> newData) {
            super.onPostExecute(newData);
            final BusStopAdapter mAdapter = new BusStopAdapter(myDataset,mRecyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.swapItems(newData);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ProgressBar... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            values[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mGoogleMap.clear();
            LocationUtility.addMarkerBusStop(mGoogleMap);
        }
    }


}
```

In the busUtility I have a method called by adapter which calculate the distance and the time from the currentLocation to bus stop and set this data in textViews. All the bus stops are saved in the local sqlite3 database.

```
public String[] getArray(Fermata currentItem) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return JsonUtility.getDistanceTime(new JSONParse().execute(currentItem).get());
}
```

In summary: get the bus stop near me(I use the haversine formula), calculate the distance from me to this bus station with json and set all this data on the recyclerview.

The problem is that recyclerview and google map are very slow and lag a lots.(many request to google?)

Comment: You have to show some sort of code with your question so we have something to go on. I don't know that you are pulling your data in the most efficient way. I don't know that you are pulling huge datasets when you only need smaller pieces of them. We can't help if you don't post an attempt.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono ok sorry, I'have writing a general question to know if there are some trips that can be useful(for example connection to db are made with a static dbOpenHelper with cursor to create model object). i will post some code as soon as possible.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono check my edit. Thank you.

Comment: Architecture design are considered too-broad questions. I suggest ask only to the part(s) where the real problem exists (Although you mentioned some suspects, but have you tried benchmarking it before you conclude it is the issue? ). Optimization question in the other hand needs a lot of time and testing in order to achieve a great results.

Comment: @Enzokie for this reason I have done a general question. What can I try?

Answer (score -1):

I really can't really tell you what is wrong with your app but i can give you some tools to improve a little bit the performance :

first use Android Lint to find code flaws :
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

After you fix all of them or the vast majority use Android Memory monitor to find out where your app is using most memory :
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html

You shouldn't use asyncTask they are depractated for more than 5 years because they are not aware of activty life cicles.

After and only after you complete the above task follow this tutorial to implement loader manager :
http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/60331340133/very-simple-example-of-a-loader-and-loadermanager

Comment: AsyncTasks are not deprecated.  They aren't always the best answer, but they have their uses.  Also, your answer doesn't really address his question-  because its too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Hi I agree that does not completely address the question but is a good starting point :), also can you please give me some examples where AsyncTask is the best option ? (Just to know about them)